# About 3DSware games

Tags: nintendo-network-id

So I have this **awesome** game on my 3DS, but it's a 3DSware game, and I have a ton of memory on the game itself. Is there any way that I can transfer this game onto my 3DSXL *without* erasing all of its memory? (I know about the full transfer I can do from one 3DS to another, but I am willing to use a computer, or whatever it takes to [at the very least] get this game transfered onto my 3DSXL *with* all of its memory, even if every game on my 3DS has to be transfered onto my 3DSXL.)

Comment: The only legit way is to use Nintendo's transfer system.  Which will remove it from the source system, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can download the game onto your 3DSXL, if you login with the same ID but I don't know about the progress that is on your 3DS.

Comment: @GiantTree Depends on the game. It's like phones. But most likely you will be able to re-download the game by signing in with the same ID but your progress will be lost.

Comment: Okay, so my game can be transfered, but I will lose my progress? Alright, I just wanted to make sure it was impossible before trying.